# What are the airworthiness requirements for transport category hybrid airships?

Tags: faa-regulations, airship, far-25

According to section 1.2 of the Airship Design Criteria ([FAA P-8110-2](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/airships/airships_regs/media/aceAirshipDesignCriteria.pdf)), the FAA limits the applicability of airship airworthiness requirements to aircraft "capable of achieving zero static heaviness during normal flight operations."

If that's the case, then under which FAR part are hybrid airships with buoyancy ratios less than 1 certified? Assuming transport category, would the FAA just use Part 25?